# Android Audio remote controls

Tags: android, audio, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

0 ICS google states that the new Audio Remote control api has been added.
I'd like to find some documentation about this new feature but i cannot find anything.
Does someone have a link or something to address me?
Thanks

Pasquale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out an example included in ICS official examples package called RandomPlayer. This example shows how to implement a music player using an Android service and also Remote Control API

Answer (score 0):

From the Android 4.0 SDK "new APIs" list: [Multimedia](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0.html#Multimedia). It looks like the type to implement is [`RemoteControlClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html).

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful. Do you know if it's possible with this new api to put audio controls on the lock screen?

Comment: Despite no written word, this is the way to enable audio controls on a  stock lock screen. It amazes me how hard was to find this piece of information.

Comment: Could you provide an example or a reference to some APIs?